# Can't allocate 2-4 Gb of RAM with new[]/ C++/Linux/ x86_64

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, x86-64

For this easy test, and the linux box with 4Gb or RAM, 0byte of swap and CPU in x86_64 mode, I can't allocate more than 1 Gb of array.

Source:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
 for(int i=0;i<33;i++) { 
  char*a=new char[1<<i];
  *a=1;
  delete[]a; 
  printf("%d\n",i);
  fflush(stdout);
 }
}
```

Run:

```
$ file test
test: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
$ ./test
...
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  St9bad_alloc
Aborted
```

There is no ulimit for memory:

```
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
```

Why the error?

Glibc is 2.3.4, kernel is 2.6.9

UPDATE: Compiler is gcc4.1

Thanks! The test definitely has a error, `1ull<<i` gives me up to 31 (2gb). This error was unintended. But the real failed code is

```
 for(j=0;j<2;j++)
  for(i=0;i<25;i++)
   some_array[j][i] = new int[1<<24];
```

so there is no sign overflow in the real code.

Size of int is 4 byte:

```
$ echo 'main(){return sizeof(int);}'| gcc -x c - && ./a.out; echo $?
4
```

the every request will be for 1<<24 * 4 = 1<<26; total memory required is 2*25*(1<<26) 3355443200 bytes + 50*sizeof(pointer) for some_array + 50*(size of new[] overhead).

Comment: Can't test, so won't answer, but isn't `1<<31` is a negative number, even on 64-bit Linux? Try `1ull<<i`.

Comment: But, but... `operator new` takes `size_t`, doesn't it? No matter what signedness `i` may be, when it's converted to `size_t`, it is unsigned, taking whatever the binary value is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** I see in other answers that the issue is most probably related with the number passed to `new[]` becoming negative. I agree that that is most probably the case, I am leaving this answer only because I think that it contains information that might be relevant in some similar cases, where the issue is not with calling `new[]` with a negative number.

---

The first question that comes to mind is whether you have enough available memory. With 4Gb RAM and no swap the total amount of memory that can be allocated to *all* processes *and* the kernel is 4Gb.

Note that even if you had more than 1Gb of memory available for the process, `malloc` and `free` (that are called underneath by `new[]` and `delete[]` might not give the memory back to the system, and they might in fact keep each one of the acquired/released blocks, so that the memory footprint of your program might go as high as 2Gb (would have to check this with the malloc implementation in your kernel, as many implementations do give back big blocks).

Finally, when you request an array of 1Gb you are requesting 1Gb of *contiguous* memory, and it might just be the case that you have much more memory but none of the blocks is large enough for that particular request.

Comment: +1 for the edit--this is good info that could easily have been the problem but for the negative size he ran into.

Comment: @dribeas: Good thinking, but this is wrong.  Linux has overcommit behavior by default, you don't actually need any RAM or swap space for allocation to succeed, and your program can later be killed without recourse when you try to access the memory that was (apparently successfully) already allocated.  Contiguity also is a problem of address space, not available RAM, since the page tables can map contiguous addresses to fragmented physical RAM.  Under x86_64 fragmented address space is unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: overcommit settings is changed for setups w/o swap, AFAIK.

Comment: Other processes are small, only some monitoring tools.

Comment: This is almost mostly bogus as Ben Voigt pointed out. Just one point to add - unless you are using some really weird malloc/free, released memory greater than the VMM page size (typically 4K) will be re-used.

Answer (score 14):

A naked constant in C is an int. A signed int.
So `1 << 31` is -2147483648.
because
`1<<31` = `0x10000000` = `-2147483648`

Try `(size_t)1 << i`

Comment: Thanks, this is a bug in my quick test. But real code have no negative sizes.

Comment: Well it is tricky for me to tell you what might be wrong with code I can't see -- I'm good but I am not that good ;-) Check out the answer by @David Rodríguez and @Ben Voigt above. They discuss other factors which may come into play.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` and `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio` on your system?  If you have memory overcommitting turned off, you may not be able to allocate all the memory on your system.  With overcommit turned on (set `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` to 0) then you should be able to allocate essentially unlimited size arrays (certainly 10s of GB) on a 64-bit system.

Comment: I know only that this system have no swap. Can this help in determing values of overcommit_* ?

Comment: No, that's independent.  You can just do 'cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory' to see what is set there.

Comment: The just is not so easy because access to the machine is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Although is generally true that on 64bit machine you have plenty of address space to allocate several GB of continuous virtual memory, you are trying to allocate it using new/malloc. New/malloc are traditionally not requests for **any memory**, but for a specific part of the memory which is allocated using the **{s,}brk** system call which basically moves the end of the process data segment. I think that you should allocate such large amount of memory using **mmap** which leaves the OS free to choose any address block.

Comment: Malloc may use both mmap and sbrk. mmap threshold for malloc implementation in glibc (ptmalloc, which is based on dlmalloc) is around several megabytes (from 2 to 16 MB); if I request more than thresold - malloc will use mmap syscall. My real code request (`new int[1<<24];`) is for 16M of ints or 64 MB which is clearly above the mmap threshold. So my problem is not in **sbrk**.